# When to account for order in counting?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

For problem, "In an urn are 5 blue, 3 red, and 2 yellow marbles. If you draw 3 marbles, what is the probability that less than $2$ will be red if you draw with replacement?", why $P(1~\text{red marble}) = (3/10) \cdot (7/10) \cdot (7/10) \cdot (3!)$?

When asking questions about picking an ice cream from $3$ flavours and $2$ toppings, we don't do $2!$?

Comment: What is the "question about picking an ice cream from 3 favour and 2 toppings" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In an urn are $5$ blue, $3$ red, and $2$ yellow marbles.  If you draw $3$ marbles, what is the probability that less than $2$ will be red if you draw with replacement?

The key words here are with replacement.  That tells you that you are looking at sequences of outcomes, so order matters.

Since the marbles are selected with replacement, the probability of drawing a red marble will be the same with each trial.  Therefore, we use the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  The probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials each with probability $p$ of success and probability $1 - p$ of failure is
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures, and $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways (orders) in which $k$ successes could occur in $n$ trials.  Since three of the ten marbles are red, $p = 3/10$ and $1 - p = 7/10$.  Since there are three trials, $n = 3$.  We wish to find $\Pr(X < 2)$.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X < 2) & = \Pr(X = 0) + \Pr(X = 1)\\
           & = \binom{3}{0}\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^0\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^3 + \binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^1\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^2
\end{align*}
Your probability for exactly one success is too large since there are only three distinguishable arrangements of one success and two failures: $(S, F, F), (F, S, F), (F, F, S)$.

In the problem about picking an ice cream from $3$ flavours and $2$ toppings, what matters is which flavour and which topping are selected, assuming one of each is permitted, not the order in which you select them.  Note that there is an implicit order of selection in that problem since you place the topping on the ice cream, not the other way around.

**Addendum:**  Let's look at a few more examples related to the marble problem above.

> In an urn are $5$ blue, $3$ red, and $2$ yellow marbles.  If you draw three marbles, what is the probability that three marbles of different colors will be selected if marbles are drawn with replacement?

There are $10$ choices for each marble, so there are $10^3$ elements in our sample space.

There are $3! = 6$ orders in which we could three marbles of different colors: $(b, r, y), (b, y, r), (r, b, y), (r, y, b), (y, b, r), (y, r, b)$, where $b$ stands for blue, $r$ stands for red, and $y$ stands for yellow.  For each such arrangement, there are $5$ ways to select the blue marble, $3$ ways to select the red marble, and $2$ ways to select the yellow marble.  Hence, the probability of selecting three different color marbles is
$$\Pr(\text{three marbles of different colors}) = \frac{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3!}{10^3}$$

> In an urn are $5$ blue, $3$ red, and $2$ yellow marbles.  If you draw three marbles, what is the probability that three marbles of different colors will be selected if marbles are drawn without replacement?

We can do this problem by taking order of selection into account.

Since marbles are drawn without replacement, there are $10$ ways to select the first marble, nine ways to select the second marble, and eight ways to select the third marble.  Hence, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ ways to select three marbles without replacement.

The number of favorable cases is the same as it is for the with replacement case.  Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{three marbles of different colors}) = \frac{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3!}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}$$

However, it is easier to do this problem without taking order into account.  There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to select three of the ten marbles.

There are five ways to select one of the five blue marbles, three ways to select one of the three red marbles, and two ways to select one of the two yellow marbles.  Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{three marbles of different colors}) = \frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

> In an urn are $5$ blue, $3$ red, and $2$ yellow marbles.  If you draw $3$ marbles, what is the probability that less than $2$ will be red if you draw without replacement?

If we take order into account, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ marbles in our sample space.

If no red marbles are selected, there are five choices for the first marble, four choices for the second marble, and three choices for the third marble, giving $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$ such selections.

If exactly one red marble is selected, there are $5$ choices for the red marble, five choices for the first non-red marble, and four choices for the second non-red marble.  There are $3$ possible orders in which the red marble could be selected: $(r, n, n), (n, r, n), (n, n, r)$, where $r$ stands for red and $n$ stands for non-red.  Hence, there are $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$ such selections.

Thus,
$$\Pr(\text{at most one red marble}) = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 + 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}$$

Again, the problem can be solved more simply by not taking order of selection into account.

There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to select three of the ten marbles.

There are $\binom{5}{0}\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select none of the five red marbles and three of the five non-red marbles.  There are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select one of the five red marbles and two of the five non-red marbles.

Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{at most one red marble}) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{0}\dbinom{5}{3} + \dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{5}{2}}{\dbinom{10}{3}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I guess I'm always confused about when to (or not to) account for ordering while applying multiplication rules. For instance, to pick a license plate with 3 digits, the number of arrangement would be 10*10*10; and here we don't do 3!. I'm wondering is it true that 3! is only needed when they are not all the same number, i.e. 10*3*10, where somehow the middle digit can't take certain numbers. Only in this case we need to do 3! ? Then how about 3*2*10?

Comment: also in question: pick 4 letters at random with replacement from P,N,D,Q, what's the probability all 4 letters are different? The answer is 4!/4^4, and we don't multiply additional 4! to the numerator. Given 4!=4*3*2*1, which means multiplication already implies ordering, which contradicts with the problem I raised above, which still needs 3!. My question remains: this is not very clear to be when multiplication rule accounts, or not accounts, for different arrangement. And hereby when do we need (not) to do n! to account for arrangements.

Comment: You are correct that you multiply by $k!$ when taking order into account when each of the $k$ objects are distinct.  For your $P, N, D, Q$ problem,  if all the letters are distinct, there are four choices for the first position, three choices for the second position, two choices for the third position, and one choice for the fourth position, giving $4!$ possible arrangements of four distinct letters.  Similarly, in the marble problem above, there are $5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3!$ ways to select one blue marble, one red marble, and one yellow marble.

Comment: I have added some additional examples to my answer, including two examples in which marbles are selected without replacement which I solved both by taking the order of selection into account and by not taking the order of selection into account.  I hope studying those examples will help you understand when and how to take order into account.